# Is it possible to run Oculus app without a headset connected?

Tags: c#, oculus

I have an Oculus Rift DK2 headset and I am developing an app for it using C# wrapper OculusWrap. It would be very helpful if it would be possible to run the Oculus code without having the heaset connected all the time. Of course there would not be any sensor inputs but there are many features that I could test without that....

So my question is, is there any way to emulate a "virtual" headset just for testing purposes? I spent a lot of time googling it and it seems there have been some ways to do it in the past but I couldn't find any that would be working nowadays.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at [VRTK] (https://github.com/ExtendRealityLtd/VRTK)? It has a nice simulator SDK that lets you play around the scene without VR hardware. You could write your own based on it if you need something more custom!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks nice but if I understand correctly, the VRTK is intented for use with Unity? I am not using Unity, I am working on a complex C# desktop app that we want to have the option to display the scene also in VR using the Oculus DK2. So we don't want so change the tools we are using but we would just like to trick it somehow to think that the Oculus headset is connected, when we need to debug something without the headset connected...